# In news feed "person X replied to a comment"—how do I see this comment?

Tags: facebook, news-feed

Often, in my news feed I'll be greeted by something like this:

[image]

So I'm curious as to what my friend wrote. However, I don't want to scroll through 100s of comments, clicking on each one to try and find where my friends reply was. Is there a way to show this specific reply to a comment?

Comment: What happens if you click on _comment_? It seems to be a link, so it might lead you to that specific comment.

Comment: Oh wow, yes that worked, why did I not think of that?? However, I tried this when the content was a photo from a page I don't like (with 100s of comments) and it only opened up the photo to full screen without showing me the corresponding comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The notifications for such things on the desktop browser version of Facebook are horribly broken, and clicking the link in the notification often does not go to the actual comment in question.

A solution I have found for this is to use the mobile version of the facebook website, as the notifications on that version of the site are far more accurate and clicking them actually does take you to the precise comment as mentioned in the notification.

To access the mobile version of Facebook, you don't actually need to be using a mobile device, you just need to click the following URL http://m.facebook.com then just click the notifications icon at the top of the screen, to access the notifications.

Comment: In 2020 the situation is even worse: now m.facebook is as broken as facebook. :(

Comment: yes, you are sadly right about that...